# HTTP POST is executed twice in a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, http, sendgrid

I use the following form to let users of my website send me a mail:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
        <form class="form" method="post" ng-submit="mySubmit()">                
            <div class="form-group">
                <input ng-model="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name:">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input ng-model="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email:">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea ng-model="message" class="form-control" rows="12" placeholder="Message:"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-theme">Send Message</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('RequestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.mySubmit = function () {
        alert($scope.name + " " + $scope.mail + " " + $scope.message);
        return $http.post('/request/addRequest', { "name": $scope.name, "mail": $scope.mail, "message": $scope.message })
    }
}])
```

Then, I realized that after clicking on `submit`, the http post is launched **twice**: the first time is immediately after clicking the button, the second time is after around 3 minutes. As a result, I always receive 2 mails.

But, `alert` is always executed once.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**PS:** Here is backend. Everything is launched twice:

```
router.post('/request/addRequest', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.post /request/addRequest")
    var name = req.body.name, mail = req.body.mail, message = req.body.message;
    console.log(name + " " + mail + " " + message);
    // using SendGrid's v3 Node.js Library
    // https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs
    var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
    var fromEmail = new helper.Email('example@gmail.com');
    var toEmail = new helper.Email('exampmle@gmail.com');
    var subject = 'subject';
    var content = new helper.Content('text/plain', 'Name: ' + name + " Mail: " + mail + " Message: " + message);
    var mail = new helper.Mail(fromEmail, subject, toEmail, content);

    var sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    var request = sg.emptyRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v3/mail/send',
        body: mail.toJSON()
    });

    sg.API(request, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error response received');
        }
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(response.body);
        console.log(response.headers);
    });
})
```

And the statut in Dev Tools is only one line:[image]

Comment: You can remove post attribute from your form element as it is redundant

Comment: do you have access to the serveur ? and see in the logs that you receive 2 http POST call ? 
Can you check on Google Chrome within the dev Network tab if there is 2 call ? or only one ? this is wierd ;)

Comment: @aorfevre I have access to the server, and the logs show it receives 2 http POST calls.

Comment: What is the response of your first (301?)? Do you have rewrites active?

Comment: and what about Google Chrome ? 2 HTTP POST are sended ?

Comment: Why do you use return $http.post and you don't call without return the $http.post ?

Comment: @Vivz after removing the post attribute, it still sends 2 mails...

Comment: @geo sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: If you do this : 
$scope.mySubmit = function () {
        alert($scope.name + " " + $scope.mail + " " + $scope.message);
        $http.post('/request/addRequest', { "name": $scope.name, "mail": $scope.mail, "message": $scope.message })
    }

Comment: can you see request sending twice in browser network?

Comment: @aseferov I don't know where we can see that under the tab "network"...

Comment: Command+Option+I (Mac)  Control+Shift+I(windows) and select netwrok tab (chrome browser), refresh page and check request when submit form

Comment: @aseferov in browser network, it shows only once, but with a status "pending".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

The reason why the status of the request is `pending` is that there is no `res.json(...)` in the backend.

After adding `res.json(...)`, the email is sent only once.